# Delete duplicated element from an mutidimension array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and `$my_array`. And there are duplicated arrays `['Mot Clé']` with diffrent `Position`
Here's the `$my_array`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Position] => 0
        [Moteur] => Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)
        [Mot Clé] => BTS esf 24
        [Site] => http://www.test.com
        [Page positionnée] => Pas de résultat
        [Titre de la page] => 
        [Date] => 28/02/2014
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Position] => 0
        [Moteur] => Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)
        [Mot Clé] => BTS esf 33
        [Site] => http://www.test.com
        [Page positionnée] => Pas de résultat
        [Titre de la page] => 
        [Date] => 28/02/2014
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Position] => 1
        [Moteur] => Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)
        [Mot Clé] => BTS esf 33
        [Site] => http://www.test.com
        [Page positionnée] => Pas de résultat
        [Titre de la page] => 
        [Date] => 28/02/2014
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Position] => 5
        [Moteur] => Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)
        [Mot Clé] => BTS esf 33
        [Site] => http://www.test.com
        [Page positionnée] => Pas de résultat
        [Titre de la page] => 
        [Date] => 28/02/2014
    )

)
```

I want to unset the duplicate an leave only the one who has the biggest `['Position']`! Any idea on how i can achiev that ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "Position" => 0,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "BTS esf 33",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 0,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Test",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 0,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "BTS esf 33",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 1,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "BTS esf 33",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 1,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Test",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 5,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "BTS esf 33",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 3,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Test",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 0,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Testing",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 8,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Testing",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
    array(
        "Position" => 9,
        "Moteur" => "Bing.com France - (Tout afficher)",
        "Mot Clé" => "Testing",
        "Site" => "http://www.test.com",
        "Page positionnée" => "Pas de résultat",
        "Titre de la page" => "",
        "Date" => "28/02/2014"
    ),
);

function sort_compare($a, $b) {
    return (($a["Position"] == $b["Position"]) ? 0 : (($a["Position"] > $b["Position"]) ? -1 : 1));
}

function remove_duplicates($array) {
    $return = array();
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($array AS $key => $value) {
        $tmp[$value["Mot Clé"]][] = $value;
    }

    foreach($tmp AS $key => $value) {
        usort($tmp[$key], "sort_compare");
    }

    foreach($tmp AS $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) && isset($value[0])) $return[] = $value[0];
    }

    return $return;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(remove_duplicates($arr));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I have also taken into consideration that you might have other types of "Mot Clé"'s in your array :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming positions appear in increasing order, I would go as follow:
 - reverse your array.
 - scan the array and store the "Mot Clé" in another array. Before storing, check it is not there already. If it is there, then remove the entry in the first array.

```
array_reverse($my_array);
$keywords = array();
foreach($my_array as $key=>$value)
{
  $keyword = $value["Mot Clé"];
  if(isset($keywords[$keyword]))
    unset($my_array[$key]);
  $keywords[$keyword] = "";
}
```

If positions do not appear in increasing order, then you would have to sort your array with positions in decreasing order beforehand.
Which could be achieved using usort():

```
usort($$my_array, function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["Position"] == $b["Position"]){ return 0;}
    else if ($a["Position"] > $b["Position"]){return -1;}
    else { return 1; }
});
```

Comment: @SpencerX is it not what " leave only the one who has the biggest ['Position']" means ?

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't :(